# Type error : unhashable type "list" , when am trying to use regex to find and count number of repetion of single word in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dictionary, screen-scraping

i am working on a problem where i open a file handle using python and let the user enter regex command manually

```
print("\t ***hello user*** ")
# simulate the operation of 'grep' on linux using python ask
# the user to enter regular expression and count the numbers 
# of lines that matched the regex

# first and most imp import module define variable
import re

di = {}

infile = input("Enter the file name: ")

regin = input("input regex command")


#pre defining file for help debug
if len(infile) < 1 : infile = 'mbox-short.txt'

# checking error if file present or not

try:
    fhand = open(infile)
except:
    # exit if file not present 
    print("Invalid entery")
    quit()


for line in fhand:
    
    #strip \n character from line using strip function
    line = line.strip()
    for w in line:
        w = re.findall(regin,line)
        di[w] = di.get(w,0) + 1
print(di)
```

**the logic for the code was to ask user to input the file and regular expression and then open file  find  the word in file matching to regex and count the number of lines where that word appeared **

```
enter code here = output
```

```
r3tr0@iCBM:~/Desktop/py/python/regex$ python3 ex1.py 
         ***hello user*** 
Enter the file name: 
input regex command^Author
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex1.py", line 33, in <module>
    di[w] = di.get(w,0) + 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

am not sure what to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for line in fhand:
    
    #strip \n character from line using strip function
    line = line.strip()
    for w in line:

        w = tuple(re.findall(regin,line))

        di[w] = di.get(w,0) + 1
print(di)
```

`re.findall(regin, line)` must be returning a `list` and you can't use `list` as key of dictionary. So, cast that `list` into `tuple`, which can be used as dictionary key.